# Does anyone know how much the Fluid Nitro Women's Sport Mountain Bike weighs?

Tags: mountain-bike

I was wondering how much the Fluid Nitro Women's Sport Mountain Bike weighs to calculate calories burned when riding

Comment: Why cannot you weight the bicycle yourself? Besides, the weight depends on the frame size. Looking at Google search results, I would estimate it to be in range 13-14 kg for frame size small, and I doubt that higher accuracy is needed in this case.

Comment: How did you find that on google? I have looked everywhere and I cannot find anything

Comment: I looked at the price tag. Bicycles of the same price range tend to weigh the same (given the same frame size and frame material). If it was 1 kg *less*, it would have cost ~1 k$ *more*. I am not sure that one kilogram of accuracy error would affect precision of your calorie burning calculation. That is because a proper measurement technique should consider a lot of factors including incline, wind direction, rolling resistance etc. Or rather, measurements should be made by specialized equipment placed in a bike's crank; that is how real serious data collection is done.

Comment: For example, calories numbers that e.g. Strava shows for non-premium accounts are based on input weight and GPS track data. They are questionable in its accuracy. They can be 90% lower or higher than the actual energy burnt. 

For Strava method, you'll need to weigh yourself. This means you can also grab your bike and weigh it with you on the same scales.

Comment: Use your bathroom scales: once with and once without the bike. Difference = weight of the bike.

Comment: @carel good idea - one can also weigh one wheel at a time and add the totals.  I've done that with a loaded bike trailer.  Just got to be careful to barely support the bike by the side and not add/remove any weight.  For the perfectionist, it helps to have the other wheel at the same height as the scale, but for practical purposes a couple centimetres difference makes no real difference given bathroom scales tend to measure in blocks of 100 grams.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.ozbargain.com.au/node/210733 says 15.3 kilograms but that's for the man's frame.  Add 100g for the woman's frame because of the longer top tube.

My google keywords were "Fluid Nitro Sport MTB" without any weight keywords.

http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2562427 also shows the same weight for the male frame.

I'd suggest you call it a round 16.0 kilos with a full water bottle.